# Why are my drawings sized relatively to the canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas defined as

```
<canvas id="field"></canvas>
```

style.css:

```
canvas#field {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 3px solid black; /* for now */
}
```

Whenever I try drawing stuff on it, like

```
var ctx = field.getContext("2d")
// circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

It always ends up being sized relatively to the canvas dimensions. If I make the canvas twice as big, the circle is also twice as big, even though my radius is always 50px. If I make my canvas a square, the circle becomes elongated downwards, and vice versa if I stretch the canvas out sideways.

How do I make the canvas treat the numbers I give it as absolute values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set canvas width and height as HTML attributes instead of CSS rules:

```
<canvas id="field" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage):

> The `<canvas>` element has only two attributes, `width` and `height`. These are both optional and can also be set using DOM properties. When no `width` and `height` attributes are specified, the canvas will initially be 300 pixels wide and 150 pixels high. The element can be sized arbitrarily by CSS, but during rendering the image is scaled to fit its layout size: if the CSS sizing doesn't respect the ratio of the initial canvas, it will appear distorted.

You can also set `width` and `height` dynamically using JavaScript:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = '500';
canvas.height = '250';
```